# forward in pytorch nn.linear gives NaN

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I am working on a Pytorch model. The training set looks like this:

```
Pclass  Sex Age SibSp   Parch   Fare    Embarked
0   3   0   1   1   0   0   1.0
1   1   1   1   1   0   3   2.0
2   3   1   1   0   0   0   1.0
3   1   1   1   1   0   3   1.0
4   3   0   1   0   0   0   1.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
886 2   0   1   0   0   0   1.0
887 1   1   0   0   0   1   1.0
888 3   1   0   1   2   0   1.0
889 1   0   1   0   0   1   2.0
890 3   0   1   0   0   0   0.0
891 rows × 7 columns
```

similar is the test set. The training_label is one hot encoded.

The model is:

```
class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
   
        # an affine operation: y = Wx + b
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(7, 10)
        self.bc1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10, 10)
        self.bc2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(10)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10, 1)
        self.bc3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(1)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.bc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.bc2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.bc3(x)
        #x = F.sigmoid(x)
        return x
    
model = Net()
```

I am calling the TensorDataset and DataLoader to load (train_data, train_label) of batchsize 100.

I am trying to call the model:

```
num_epochs = 1
# Repeat for given number of epochs
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        
    # Train with batches of data
    for xb,yb in train_dl:
        pred = model(xb)
        
        yb = torch.unsqueeze(yb, 1)
        
        print(pred, yb)
        #print('grad', model.fc1.weight.grad)
        
        l = loss(pred, yb)
        print('loss',l)
                    
        # 3. Compute gradients
        l.backward()
            
        # 4. Update parameters using gradients
        optimizer.step()
            
        # 5. Reset the gradients to zero
        optimizer.zero_grad()
```

After some time, I am getting NaN as output from the pred = model(xb). As you can see, I am running for only 1 epoch, so I am getting the NaN in the first epoch for some batch.

I am not sure why it is happening. I checked and found some solutions to it, like reducing the epoch but my epoch is already very low. I also have preprocessed the dataset so that all the inputs are 0,1,2,3 or 4 (like I preprocessed Age, Gender etc).

I am not getting any error message but I can see the outputs as NaN and so is the loss of course, as I print them. I also tried different optimization, loss. Right now I am using:

```
#model.cuda()
#loss = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
loss = F.mse_loss

learning_rate = 0.0001
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)
```

I also tried BCEWithLogitsLoss. nn.BCELoss gives the error that the inputs should be between 0 and 1 (and here some inputs are becoming Nan)

Can anyone help and explain what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried normalizing your features? What is your output feature (*i.e.* the target)?

Comment: maybe try not to use batchnorm but dropout instead (thats more common for fc models). And Im pretty sure you shouldnt apply batchnorm to the last layer, maybe try to remove that.

Comment: Yes @Ivan I normalized.

Comment: And @Theodor okay I am trying it. Good suggestion. Thanks